# Is my old B1 visa valid after my green card is approved

Tags: visas

I have a green card and returned to home country before Covid and never travelled back to US. Now my green card is invalid. I have a B1 visa that is still valid. Can I travel to USA with the B1 visa or do I need to get a new B1 visa?

Comment: "Now my green card is invalid." You don't know that for sure. Abandonment of residence is a subjective determination that looks at many factors, not just length of absence alone. Do you wish to continue residing in the US?